# Response header in Symfony2 dosen't change

Tags: symfony

I'm developing a website using `symfony2`.

First I started everything was fine, redirects returns `301` response, on server error `Symfony` returns `300` response ..., but now every time I using `redirect Response` symfony returns a response with `200` status and `meta refresh` to redirect. Aslo when an internal server error occurs it return a response with `200` status .

In another situation I tried to create `RSS` feed, although I sets `Content-Type: application/xml` in client-side content-type is `text-html`.

Is there something wrong with `Symfony` config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You left a BOM mark or a whitespace character outside of php tags somewhere?

Before doing a `return new Response...` try:

```
if (headers_sent($filename, $linenum)) {
    echo "Headers already sent in $filename on line $linenum\n";
    exit; 
}
```

Comment: You're right. there was a whitespace after php tag. But why it happens? What is the connection between setting header and a whitespace character?

Comment: PHP sends the response's headers when you start to output any content (in other words, the whitespace makes web-server think you're ready to send a piece of content to a client). So the headers are sent with the response as well, and after they're sent you can't change them - php will just ignore it. Symfony does magic here and checks if headers were already sent, then it replaces the 30x-redirect with meta tag.